# Javascript localecompare - Uppercase letters to be sorted first

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array of objects containing `lastName` and `firstName` attributes. I want the objects to be sorted by `lastName` in `asc` order and then by `firstName` in `asc` order if the objects have the same `lastName`.

Below is the sort order (standard alphabetical sort order) I need.

```
[symbols, numbers, 'A-Z', 'a-z']
```

I have used `localeCompare` but it sorts the strings in the following sort order.

```
[symbols, numbers, 'a-z', 'A-Z']
```

The lowercase letters comes before the uppercase letters

For ex: If the array contains the following elements

```
let guests = [
{
lastName: "guest",
firstName: "abc"
},
{
lastName: "Guest",
firstName: "test"
},
{
lastName: "guest",
firstName: "Abc"
},
{
lastName: "guest",
firstName: "123"
}
];
```

I want the objects to be sorted like:

```
[
    {
    lastName: "Guest",
    firstName: "test"
    },
    {
    lastName: "guest",
    firstName: "123"
    },
    {
    lastName: "guest",
    firstName: "Abc",
    },
    {
    lastName: "guest",
    firstName: "abc"
    }
]
```

But the result I get is

```
[
    {
    lastName: "guest",
    firstName: "123"
    },
    {
    lastName: "guest",
    firstName: "abc"
    },
    {
    lastName: "guest",
    firstName: "Abc",
    },
    {
    lastName: "Guest",
    firstName: "test"
    }
]
```

Below is the code I tried.

```js
let guests = [
              {
                lastName: "guest",
                firstName: "abc"
              },
              {
                lastName: "Guest",
                firstName: "test"
              },
              {
                lastName: "guest",
                firstName: "Abc"
              },
              {
                lastName: "guest",
                firstName: "123"
              }
            ];

            guests.sort((a, b) => {
              if (_.get(a, 'lastName') === _.get(b, 'lastName')) {
                return _.get(a, 'firstName', '').localeCompare(_.get(b, 'firstName', ''));
              } else {
                return _.get(a, 'lastName', '').localeCompare(_.get(b, 'lastName', ''));
              }
            });
            
             console.log(guests);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

I understood from the documentation for `localeCompare` that it accepts an `options` object where we can specify `caseFirst` attribute specifying the sort order for uppercase and lowercase letters.

The below code snippet which uses the `options` parameter produces the output I expect but the problem with that is, it is not supported in all the browsers yet.

```js
     let guests = [
        {
        lastName: "guest",
        firstName: "abc"
        },
        {
        lastName: "Guest",
        firstName: "test"
        },
        {
        lastName: "guest",
        firstName: "Abc"
        },
        {
        lastName: "guest",
        firstName: "123"
        }
        ];
        
    guests.sort((a, b) => {
                          if (_.get(a, 'lastName') === _.get(b, 'lastName')) {
                            return _.get(a, 'firstName', '').localeCompare(_.get(b, 'firstName', ''), undefined, {caseFirst: 'upper'});
                          } else {
                            return _.get(a, 'lastName', '').localeCompare(_.get(b, 'lastName', ''), undefined, {caseFirst: 'upper'});
                          }
                        });
                        
    console.log(guests);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Is there any way to accomplish the result without using the options parameter. Is there a custom sort method that I can pass to JS `array.sort()` that would accomplish my goal. Please help.

Comment: can you share the working snippet?

Comment: I have already shared the custom sort method I tried.

Comment: You can use `<>` from toolbar to create a working snippet.

Comment: Thanks. I have added working snippets to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Since `a` and `A` are considered equal in case-insensitive comparisons, their sort order is unspecified. You need to check if they match, and apply your custom sort if they don't.

```
guests.sort((a,b) => {
    return _.get(a, 'lastName', '').localeCompare(_.get(b, 'lastName', ''))
    || _.get(a, 'firstName', '').localeCompare(_.get(b, 'firstName', ''))
    || (_.get(a, 'lastName', '') > _.get(b, 'lastName', '') ? 1 : -1);
});
```

This will sort by last name, then by first name, then (if both are equal) it will sort uppercase before lowercase (because that's how a binary string comparison works).

Comment: Tried the code you provided. I get the same result. Lowercase letters comes before Uppercase.